# Confused about C++11 scoped enumerations

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I'm in the process of modernizing a code base and was about to switch from old-style, nested enum definitions to **Scoped Enumerations** (since C++11..??)

In this particular example we're using enums for flags -
Except the compiler won't handle bitwise OR for the variant with scoped enumerations, even when explicitly providing the type as `int`.

Could anybody enlighten me what I'm missing here and why the two flavours of declaring enums are apparently not equivalent?

The compiler error message when using scoped enumerations is

```
no match for 'operator|' (operand types are 'DrawingStyle' and 'DrawingStyle')
```

A minimal sample snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class DrawingStyle : int {
      Fill  =    1,
      Line  =    2
};

struct DrawingStyle2 {
 enum {
      Fill  =    1,
      Line  =    2
    };
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
#if BROKEN
    auto test = DrawingStyle::Fill | DrawingStyle::Line;
#else
    auto test = DrawingStyle2::Fill | DrawingStyle2::Line;
#endif

    std::cout << "Result: "<< test << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Link to sample: https://godbolt.org/z/48x3ccx77

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it. You'll have to provide overloaded operators for all the things you want to do with enums if you make this change.

Comment: With `enum class`, the enumeration values are strongly typed and cannot be implicitly converted to integers or other enumeration types. This helps prevent subtle bugs that can occur when different enumeration types are mixed. So unless you provide an explicit `|` operator for user-defined type

Comment: Check out `std::to_underlying` aka `template<typename E> [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto to_underlying(const E e) noexcept { return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e); }`

Comment: @MatG Nice... but C++23 ;-(((

Comment: @ATV Not the implementation I posted, it's just a `static_cast`

Comment: @MatG Sure. I thought you were advocating using the new `to_underlying` which is equivalent to the latter. Not long, though..